# How attach names of a list within ggtitle into a map function

Tags: r, ggplot2, lapply, ggtitle

I would have the follwing example

```
plot_list2 = split(mtcars, mtcars$cyl) %>% 
              map(function(q) ggplot(q, aes(x= mpg)) + 
                 geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..), 
                 color="darkblue", fill="lightblue")+ 
                 geom_density(alpha=.2, fill="#FF6666") + 
                 theme_classic()+ 
                 ggtitle(sprintf('Distribution for', names(q))))
```

My aim is to use a unique code so that in the `ggtitle` I can attach each names  for the list on top generated with `split`. What should I change here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will do like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
plot_list2 = split(mtcars, mtcars$cyl) %>%
  map(function(q) ggplot(q, aes(x= mpg)) + 
        geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..), 
                       color="darkblue", fill="lightblue")+ 
        geom_density(alpha=.2, fill="#FF6666") + 
        theme_classic()+
          labs(title = paste0("distribution for cyl ",unique(q$cyl))))
```

because `cyl` is unique in each element of the list created with `split` you can use the values of `cly` to plot the title. Here I used `labs` instead of `GGtitle` but should be the same. Furthermore you do not need necessarily `purrr::map`. The `base::lapply` here works the same.
Remember to explicit the library you use in the example code (i.e. `library(dyplr)` and `library(purrr)`